# Not to render all columns in UI Django HTML Template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models

In my UI I can see all the columns as default. I do not want to view all the columns in my UI, how do do that?

In this picture I have four columns by default I do not want to view EMAIL as the default

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "in my UI"? Are you talking about the [admin interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/) or something you built?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  please mention if you are talking about the admin interface or something you've built on your own.

My answer will solve your problem for the **admin interface**.

Let's suppose in the `admin.py` file, you've created a view for a particular model named **Users**, with the following fields:

1. pet_name
2. parent_name
3. last_visit

So, the class **Users** should ve something like below.

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class Users(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pet_name', 'parent_name', 'last_visit']
```

You should rename the list items according to what you've set in your model.